# Read and write bytes in C (from/in file)

Tags: c, file, input, byte, output

I have to solve the following problem in **C** for the operating systems class:

At the command line three file are given, two for input, one for output.
The output file is obtained from input files, as follows: 10 bytes from
the first file, 20 bytes from the second file, next 10  bytes from the
first file, next 20 bytes from the second file and so on, until
an input file is finished.

Simple but inefficient solution: read and write groups of 10 / 20 bytes.
An efficient (but not simple) solution: read and write blocks
with 5000 bytes.

I tried this for the simple solution. But it doesn't work... Can anyone help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]){
if (argc != 4){
    printf("%s", "Usage: c4h filename\n");
    return 0;
}

int c1,c2,i;
FILE *in1;
FILE *in2;
FILE *out;

in1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
in2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
out = fopen(argw[3], "wb");


if (in1 == NULL){
    printf("%s", "File not found!\n");
    return 0;
}

if (in2 == NULL){
    printf("%s", "File not found!\n");
    return 0;
}

while(feof(in1)!=0 && feof(in2)!=0){
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        if(feof(in1)!=0){
            c1 = fgetc(in1);
            fputc(c1,out);
        }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(feof(in2)!=0){
            c2 = fgetc(in2);
            fputc(c2,out);
        }

}

fclose(in1);
fclose(in2);
fclose(out);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Have you tried either of the solutions? Are you required to optimize it or is the inefficient solution enough?

Comment: I'd start with three `FILE` pointers and a loop. Beyond that, not much to comment on since you've presented no code with more specific questions.

Comment: The inefficient solution should be enough. I read and tried to understand some C tutorials but I still don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: Definitely go with the easier "inefficient" solution first.  Thanks to caching by the OS and/or hardware, it won't make nearly as much of a difference as you seem to think it will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were three problems with your code:

1. Typo with `argw` instead of `argv`
2. Missing closing `}` for the while loop
3. `feof(file)!=0` evaluates to true when you are at the eof, the exact opposite of the condition you want, replace with `!eof(file)` which evaluates to true only if you are not at eof

And one smaller problem, you redefine the variable `i` in your for loops: `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` should be `for(i=0;i<10;i++)` since you define `i` earlier in the code.

You should try compiling your code before taking it to SO! The code you posted didn't even compile for me. Here's the working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]){
if (argc != 4){
    printf("%s", "Usage: c4h filename\n");
    return 0;
}

int c1,c2,i;
FILE *in1;
FILE *in2;
FILE *out;

in1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
in2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
out = fopen(argv[3], "wb");


if (in1 == NULL){
    printf("%s", "File not found!\n");
    return 0;
}

if (in2 == NULL){
    printf("%s", "File not found!\n");
    return 0;
}

while(!feof(in1) && !feof(in2)){
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        if(!feof(in1)){
            c1 = fgetc(in1);
            fputc(c1,out);
        }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(!feof(in2)){
            c2 = fgetc(in2);
            fputc(c2,out);
        }

        }
}

fclose(in1);
fclose(in2);
fclose(out);
return 0;
};
```

Comment: Happy to help, if this answer solved your problem, do everyone a favor by "accepting" it (pressing the green check mark next to it)